# Using specific contextmenu with listview specific items in android

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, overriding, contextmenu

I have a `ListView` and i have set a context menu to appear when a listview item is long-pressed. But i want different menu for different listview items?

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // other stuff
    registerForContextMenu(listView);  
}
```

And the onCreateContextMenu:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
       menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Buy");  
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove");  
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Wishlist");  
   }
```

Some Item should have `Buy` or `Remove`, but they may have `both`.

How do i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");

    if(shouldHaveBuyButton)
    {
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Buy");  
    }
    if(shouldHaveRemoveButton)
    {
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove");  
    } 
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Wishlist");  
}
```

The `shouldHaveButton` logic is up to your app. If you could post more code about it we could help you more

Comment: No thats not i want! i want to know from where do i get `shouldHaveBuyButton` for specific list item ?  @fernandocarvalhosa

Comment: Thats something we can't give you without understanding your logic hahah.

What are the conditions to show the Buy or Remove button in your app?